# Configure codeigniter on a subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi everyone, 
    I've been having issues with accessing a codeigniter site.
    I uploaded on my sub domain. Pls i need your help. I have a domain called`www.mydomain.com` and a sub-domain called`www.app.mydomain.com`.
    I uploaded a CI site to`www.app.mydomain.com`.
    What changes do i need to make to config file of the CI to access this site in my sub-domain. presently i got `ERROR 404`.
    Pls I need an example to follow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check your $config["base_url"] variable at application/config/config.php file. You have to assign it your domain name like :

for example.com

```
$config["base_url"] = "http://example.com
```

for m.example.com

```
$config["base_url"] = "http://m.example.com"
```

for www.example.com

```
$config["base_url"] = "http://www.example.com"
```

Comment: It is always good to end it with `/` `$config["base_url"] = "http://www.example.com/"`

Comment: Thanks @Erol KESKIN I forgot to mention that I also used .htaccess to remove the index.php. Do I need to make changes anywhere else

Comment: Thanks @wolfgang1983. Noted